# Implementing CollectionChanged

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light

I have added `CollectionChanged eventhandler(onCollectionChanged)` to one of the `ObservableCollection` property.

I have found out that `onCollectionChanged` method gets invoked only in case of add items or remove items to the collection, but not in the case of collection item gets edited.

I would like to know how to send the list/collection of newly added, removed and edited items in a single collection.

Thanks.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You have to add a `PropertyChanged` listener to each item (which must implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`) to get notification about editing objects in a observable list.

```
public ObservableCollection<Item> Names { get; set; }
public List<Item> ModifiedItems { get; set; }

public ViewModel()
{
   this.ModifiedItems = new List<Item>();

   this.Names = new ObservableCollection<Item>();
   this.Names.CollectionChanged += this.OnCollectionChanged;
}

void OnCollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.NewItems != null)
    {
        foreach(Item newItem in e.NewItems)
        {
            ModifiedItems.Add(newItem);

            //Add listener for each item on PropertyChanged event
            newItem.PropertyChanged += this.OnItemPropertyChanged;         
        }
    }

    if (e.OldItems != null)
    {
        foreach(Item oldItem in e.OldItems)
        {
            ModifiedItems.Add(oldItem);

            oldItem.PropertyChanged -= this.OnItemPropertyChanged;
        }
    }
}

void OnItemPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Item item = sender as Item;
    if(item != null)
       ModifiedItems.Add(item);
}
```

*Maybe you have to check if some item is already in the ModifedItems-List (with List's method Contains(object obj)) and only add a new item if the result of that method is **false**.*

The class `Item` must implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`. See this [example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743695(v=vs.100).aspx) to know how. As Robert Rossney said you can also make that with `IEditableObject` - if you have that requirement.

Comment: This will throw an exception on both Add and Remove operations unless you modify the code to check whether e.NewItems and e.OldItems is null before trying to foreach over them.

Comment: Why do you need this ModifiedItems list, when you have Names collection?

Answer (score 11):

An `ItemsControl` listens to `CollectionChanged` to manage the display of the collection of items it's presenting on the screen.  A `ContentControl` listens to `PropertyChanged` to manage the display of the specific item that it's presenting on the screen.  It's pretty easy to keep the two concepts separate in your mind once you understand this.

Tracking whether or not an item is edited isn't something either of these interfaces does.  Property changes aren't edits - that is, they don't necessarily represent some kind of user-initiated change to the state of the object.  For instance, an object might have an `ElapsedTime` property that's being continuously updated by a timer; the UI needs to be notified of these property-change events, but they certainly don't represent changes in the object's underlying data.

The standard way to track whether or not an object is edited is to first make that object implement `IEditableObject`.  You can then, internally to the object's class, decide what changes constitute an edit (i.e. require you to call `BeginEdit`) and what changes don't.  You can then implement a boolean `IsDirty` property that gets set when `BeginEdit` is called and cleared when `EndEdit` or `CancelEdit` is called.  (I really don't understand why that property isn't part of `IEditableObject`; I haven't yet implemented an editable object that didn't require it.)

Of course, there's no need to implement that second level of abstraction if you don't need it - you can certainly listen `PropertyChanged` event and just assume that the object has been edited if it gets raised.  It really depends on your requirements.

Answer (score 7):

My edit to '[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4588586/638977)' is rejected!
So I put my edit here:

```
void OnCollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
if (e.NewItems != null)
{
    foreach(Item newItem in e.NewItems)
    {
        ModifiedItems.Add(newItem);

        //Add listener for each item on PropertyChanged event
        if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add)
            newItem.PropertyChanged += this.ListTagInfo_PropertyChanged;
        else if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove)
            newItem.PropertyChanged -= this.ListTagInfo_PropertyChanged;
    }
}

// MSDN: OldItems:Gets the list of items affected by a Replace, Remove, or Move action.  
//if (e.OldItems != null) <--- removed
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I *think* that populating the `ObservableCollection` with items that implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` will cause the `CollectionChanged` event to fire when an item raises its `PropertyChanged` notification.

On second thought, I think you need to use `BindingList<T>` to get individual item changes to propagate in this way out-of-the-box.

Otherwise, you'll need to manually subscribe to each item's change notifications and raise the `CollectionChanged` event. Note that if you're creating your own, derived `ObservableCollection<T>`, you'll have to subscribe at instantiation and on `Add()` and `Insert()`, and unsubscribe on `Remove()`, `RemoveAt()` and `Clear()`. Otherwise, you can subscribe to the `CollectionChanged` event and use the added and removed items from the event args to subscribe/unsubscribe.

Comment: That is correct in that you will NOT get change notifications when the items within the container change.

Comment: 1up for mentioning BindingList. It actually works well with WPF and is IMHO in many cases better then ObservableCollection.

Answer (score 2):

in winforms, `BindingList` is standard practice.  in WPF & Silverlight, you are usually stuck working with `ObservableCollection` and need to listen for `PropertyChanged` on each item

Comment: Afaik BindingList actually works pretty well with WPF.

Answer (score 2):

`INotifyCollectionChanged` is not one in the same with `INotiftyPropertyChanged`. Changing properties of underlying objects does not in any way suggest the collection has changed.

One way to achieve this behavior is to create a custom collection which will interrogate the object once added and register for the `INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged` event; it would then need to de-register appropriately when an item is removed.

One caveat with this approach is when your objects are nested N levels deep. To solve this you will need to essentially interrogate each property using reflection to determine if it is perhaps yet another collection implementing `INotifyCollectionChanged` or other container which will need to be traversed.

Here is a rudimentary un-tested example...

```
    public class ObservableCollectionExt<T> : ObservableCollection<T>
    {
        public override event System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler CollectionChanged;

        protected override void SetItem(int index, T item)
        {
            base.SetItem(index, item);

            if(item is INotifyPropertyChanged)
                (item as INotifyPropertyChanged).PropertyChanged += new PropertyChangedEventHandler(OnPropertyChanged);
        }

        protected override void ClearItems()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < this.Items.Count; i++)
                DeRegisterINotifyPropertyChanged(this.IndexOf(this.Items[i]));

            base.ClearItems();
        }

        protected override void InsertItem(int index, T item)
        {
            base.InsertItem(index, item);
            RegisterINotifyPropertyChanged(item);
        }

        protected override void RemoveItem(int index)
        {
            base.RemoveItem(index);
            DeRegisterINotifyPropertyChanged(index);
        }

        private void RegisterINotifyPropertyChanged(T item)
        {
            if (item is INotifyPropertyChanged)
                (item as INotifyPropertyChanged).PropertyChanged += new PropertyChangedEventHandler(OnPropertyChanged);
        }

        private void DeRegisterINotifyPropertyChanged(int index)
        {
            if (this.Items[index] is INotifyPropertyChanged)
                (this.Items[index] as INotifyPropertyChanged).PropertyChanged -= OnPropertyChanged;
        }

        private void OnPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            T item = (T)sender;
            OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset, item)); 
        }
    }
```

Comment: This will fail. Constructor of NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs throws the following exception when you add an item as a parameter: `System.ArgumentException: 'Reset action must be initialized with no changed items.'`

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code:

**-my Model:**

```
 public class IceCream: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int liczba;

    public int Liczba
    {
        get { return liczba; }
        set { liczba = value;
        Zmiana("Liczba");
        }
    }

    public IceCream(){}

//in the same class implement the below-it will be responsible for track a changes

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void Zmiana(string propertyName) 
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null) 
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

And in my class PersonList implement method responsible for active increasing the value  of one after button click in AppBarControl

```
async private void Add_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        List<IceCream> items = new List<IceCream>();
        foreach (IceCream item in IceCreamList.SelectedItems)
        {
            int i=Flavors.IndexOf(item);
            Flavors[i].Liczba =item.Liczba+ 1;
            //Flavors.Remove(item);

            //item.Liczba += 1;

           // items.Add(item);
           // Flavors.Add(item);
        }

        MessageDialog d = new MessageDialog("Zwiększono liczbę o jeden");
        d.Content = "Zwiększono liczbę o jeden";
        await d.ShowAsync();


        IceCreamList.SelectedIndex = -1;
    }
}
```

I hope that it will be useful for someone to
Note that:

```
private ObservableCollection<IceCream> Flavors;
```

-

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution I found to this limitation, is to remove the item using `RemoveAt(index)` then add the modified item on the same index using `InsertAt(index)` and thus the ObservableCollection will notify the View.