# ObservableCollection not updating the listview

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have an ObservableCollection which is viewed in a custom listbox. I need the listbox to update the view according to changes applied, like inserting new feeds or removing feeds from the ObservableCollection

parts of code are available below

```
public class lbl
{
    public ObservableCollection<feed> ModifiedItems 
        = new ObservableCollection<feed>();

    public lbl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        listBox1.ItemsSource = ModifiedItems ;
    }

    public void update(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var x = ModifiedItems.Last();
        listBox1.Items.Add(x);
    }
}

public class feed
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int source_id { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string source_icon { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }
    public string pudate { get; set; }
}
```

XAML

```
<ListBox x:Name="listBox1" >
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate >
        <DataTemplate >
            <StackPanel Width="400" Margin="20" >
                <Button x:Name="pic"  Tag="{Binding Id}">
                    <Button.Template>
                        <ControlTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding title}" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="28" Tag="{Binding Id}"/>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Button.Template>
                </Button>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding pudate}" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="24"/>
                <Image Source="{Binding source_icon}" Width="100" Height="60"/>
           </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Note: This is not part of the code.
It gives me the error when trying to add an Item "Operation not supported on read-only collection."

I tried the solution posted here [Implementing CollectionChanged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4588359/implementing-collectionchanged) and still I get the same error.

Any help please, Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

The problem is with your update method:

```
 public void update(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     var x = ModifiedItems.Last();
     listBox1.Items.Add(x);
 }
```

The `ItemsSource` of your `ListBox` is set to the  `ModifiedItems` which is an `ObservableCollection`. Therefore if you add or remove items from this collection, the `ListBox` UI will update automatically. For example, to add a new items to your view simply do the following:

```
ModifiedItems.Add(new feed());
```

This is the whole point of an `ObservableCollection`, the view can observe it!

If, rather than adding / removing items, you are updating existing items, you will need to make `feed` implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're setting the `ItemsSource` of the ListBox, you're binding the `ModifiedItems` collection to it.

This means you have to modify `ModifiedItems`, and not the `ListBox` to add/remove items, which then will update accordingly.

```
public void update(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var x = ModifiedItems.Last();
    ModifiedItems.Items.Add(x);
}
```

Why you want to duplicate the last item is beyond me. But that's the change you need to do.